# Соединение картинок в одну

Tags: python, изображения, telegram, бот, aiogram

У меня бот телеграмм соединяет 2 картинки
но проблема в том что выходит ошибка images do not match

вот код

```
import os
from typing import Union

from PIL import Image
from aiogram.types import ContentTypes, Message, InputFile
from asyncio.tasks import sleep
from io import BufferedWriter

from utils.make_data.qrcode import make_image_qrcode


def make_emulator(code: Union[str, int]):
qrcode_img_dir = make_image_qrcode(f'{code}')
qrcode_img = Image.open(qrcode_img_dir)
emulator_app = Image.open('./data/emulator/pytka.jpg')

x1 = emulator_app.size[0] // 2 - qrcode_img.size[0] // 2
x2 = emulator_app.size[0] // 2 + qrcode_img.size[0] // 2
y1 = 523 - qrcode_img.size[1] // 2
y2 = 280 + qrcode_img.size[1] // 2

emulator_app.paste(qrcode_img, (x1, y1, x2, y2))
emulator_dir = (f'./data/tmp/emulator_{code}.png')
emulator_app.save(emulator_dir)
os.remove(qrcode_img_dir)
```

Что делать?

Comment: Что делать?` - для начала добавить лог ошибки

Comment: А вообще, вероятно, у вас приложение запускается по одному пути, и вы не так написали локальные. Попробуйте принтануть пути обоих изображений или заменить их на глобальные.